# Putting heat on the cooling/heat/overheat/thermal tag synonyms

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

The tags [cooling](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cooling), [heat](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/heat), [overheat](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/overheat), and [thermal](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/thermal) seem to be synonymous.

Personally, I would set [cooling](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cooling) as the master tag, but I wanted to leave that up for discussion.

For all I know it would be clearly better to have the true tag be [thermal-management](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/thermal-management), say (currently unused).

Comment: Brilliant revision, @random. I think cooling is fine for the primary tag. Thermal management is a bit more cumbersome.

Comment: Hm. Still, one could argue that something "overheating" does not always imply "cooling" or vice-versa.

Comment: Yes, but do people actually use the tags precisely enough that they are distinct subjects of interest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that [cooling](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cooling) is probably best here, as computers generating heat *always* means "let's get rid of it". Plus there are ancient companies like "PC Power & Cooling" so this is an established term.

All the above are retagged and synonymized to cooling.